# Standard output and Pipe use in exec

Tags: c, exec, fork, pipe

I'm having problems understanding the right use of the pipe in UNIX Systems.
I have a main process which create a child process. The child process must run a different program from the father, he has to make some operation and then the child must communicate to the father the results.
However in the child process I have to print on the terminal the partial results of these operations.
I'm trying with a test program to do so, but I'm a bit stuck right now. This is the main test program

TEST.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

  int mypipe[2];
  pid_t pid;
  char readbuffer[6];

  pipe(mypipe);

  if((pid = fork()) == 0){
    close(mypipe[0]);
    dup2(mypipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execlp("./proc", "./proc", NULL);
  } else {

  wait(-1);
  close(mypipe[1]);
  read(mypipe[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
  printf("%s", readbuffer); 
  }
}
```

And the c file of the ./proc program is this:
PROC.C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  printf("check\n");

  return 0;
}
```

With this solution, the proc program can't print anything on the terminal. How do I make the proc program to print on the terminal AND on the pipe so the main program can read from there???
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you redirect stdout to the parent program, you can still use stderr. Just call `fprintf(stderr, ...)` instead of `printf(...)` when you want to print to the console.

Comment: Can I use another way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your "proc" program to print in terminal for log/debug infos, u can use fprintf and stderr:

```
fprintf(stderr, "What you need to print\n");
```

You can also see where your program is writing, use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)